# Android Emulator debugging Google Maps Eclipse app

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-api

I'm attempting to run an android app using the Google Api's library and am receiving a Failure to launch error when debugging upon entering an address into the input field.

Here is the error: http://s1278.beta.photobucket.com/user/cetmrw791346/media/wdyl_zps08bbe17f.png.html?sort=3&o=0

and

Here are the relevant files:

AWhereDoYouLive.java

```
package com.example.wheredoyoulive;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AWhereDoYouLive extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        final EditText addressfield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.launchmap);
        button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    // Perform action on click
                    String address = addressfield.getText().toString();
                    address = address.replace(' ', '+');
                    Intent geoIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + address));
                    startActivity(geoIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    AlertDialog ad = adb.create();
                    ad.setMessage("Failed to Launch");
                    ad.show();

                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Please enter your home address."
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:autoText="true"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/launchmap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Map"
    /> 
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Unlocking Android, Chapter 1."
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wheredoyoulive"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" >

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:name="com.example.wheredoyoulive.AWhereDoYouLive"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/> 

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity> 

    </application>
<users-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Create an AVD using Google API's and then run using it.

Answer (score 0):

When double-checking the Google services setup page: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html it looks as if Google Play services isn’t supported by any of the available Android emulators.

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around to make a Google Map API V2 to work on your emulator, please read the second part of the following blog post I wrote for more information:

[Google Map API V2 in Emulator](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527)